# Mounted network share does not list all subfolders

Tags: command-line, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am running Ubuntu Server CLI i386 version and have mounted several network shares by editing the /etc/fstab file and then issuing a mount -a command. All 4 of these shares work, except I am having a curious problem with the largest one in particular.

The share in question has about 186 folders in it, but when I cd into that directory and ls to see the contents, only 116 are shown. Everything after the 116th folder, listed alphabetically, is not shown. At first I wondered if maybe there was just a limit to the amount of items that are shown by default so I ran ls -a -l and it still shows only 116 items (118 if you count the . and .. - which suggests 116 isn't any sort of hard limit).

I know what items it's not showing so I tried to cd directly into one of the "missing" folders just to see if I could get there and I can. I tried several, actually, and am able to access them all.

I can see and access these on several windows machines.

The line for this particular mount from the fstab file is as follows (maybe I am missing an option?)

```
//designation/Share\040Name /media/shares/share cifs credentials=/home/username/.credentialfile,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

**EDIT**

Some other relevant information:

Of the 4 shares, 1 is connected directly as NAS, 2 are connected to a windows PC and shared, and the one that I am experiencing this problem with is an external drive connected directly to the router via USB

The share I am having a problem with also has a space in the share name where as the others don't. At first the fstab file didn't like this, so I escaped the space via \040

**EDIT 2**

I fixed my issue. Playing on @terdon's suspicion I tried to SSH into my router to see if I could ls the contents directly there but didn't have an SSH server running on it. Ended up flashing it with custom firmware. SSH'd in and I can ls the contents there now. Went back over the ubuntu server and I an also ls the contents there (after fixing up the fstab).

Not sure exactly what the problem was but had something to do with the router. The new firmware renamed the share and replaced the space with an underscore so it could have either been the space, or the official firmware for my router had a bug.